# Trying to run android app from eclipse: stuck between "out of heap space" and "failed to create jvm"

Tags: android, eclipse, heap-memory

I am trying to launch an android app from within eclipse. If my eclipse.ini contains

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx512m
```

then I get "out of heap space". If I increase Xmx to 1024 while keeping Xms at 512, I get "failed to create jvm" when I start eclipse. If I set Xms to 1024 instead, eclipse fails to start without any error messages.

What can I do to get it to work? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should specify the path to your Oracle JDK/JVM as described at http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini